# java bitmap Ошибка

Tags: java, android, apk

**Ошибка:**

```
12-31 14:10:47.133  3473  3473 D WakeAnimationView: [AnimationView] keyCode:0
12-31 14:10:47.133  3473  3473 D WakeAnimationView: [init] begin
12-31 14:10:47.133  3473  3473 D WakeAnimationView: [startAnimation] begin
12-31 14:10:47.134  3473  3473 D WakeAnimationView: [startAnimation] end
12-31 14:10:47.134  3473  3473 D WakeAnimationView: [init] end
12-31 14:10:47.134  3473  3473 D WakeAnimationView: [AnimationView] end
12-31 14:10:47.134  3473  3473 D WakeMainActivity: [onCreate] end
12-31 14:10:47.135  3473  3489 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2
12-31 14:10:47.135  3473  3489 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.wheatek.wakegesture, PID: 3473
12-31 14:10:47.135  3473  3489 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width must be > 0
12-31 14:10:47.135  3473  3489 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.graphics.Bitmap.checkWidthHeight(Bitmap.java:410)
12-31 14:10:47.135  3473  3489 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:732)
12-31 14:10:47.135  3473  3489 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.wheatek.wakegesture.view.AnimationView.run(AnimationView.java:201)
12-31 14:10:47.135  3473  3489 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
12-31 14:10:47.137   717   732 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.wheatek.wakegesture/.MainActivity
12-31 14:10:47.142   717   732 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.android.settings/.Settings$GestureSettingsActivity
```

**файлы:**

[Bitmap.java](https://github.com/LineageOS/android_frameworks_base/blob/cm-14.1/graphics/java/android/graphics/Bitmap.java#L680)

AnimationView.java:

```
package com.wheatek.wakegesture.view;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import com.wheatek.wakegesture.R;
import com.wheatek.wakegesture.StartApps;

public class AnimationView extends View implements Runnable {
    private boolean is_startAnimationTwo = false;
    private Bitmap mBitmap = null;
    private int mBitmapHeight = 0;
    private int mBitmapWidth = 0;
    private Context mContext;
    private int mHeightLen = 5;
    private int mKeyCode = 0;
    private int mLeft = 0;
    private Paint mPaint = null;
    private float mPersent = 0.0f;
    private Bitmap mTempBitmap = null;
    private int mTop = 0;
    private int mWidthLen = 4;
    private int sleep_time;

    public AnimationView(Context context, int keyCode) {
        super(context);
        Log.d("WakeAnimationView", "[AnimationView] keyCode:" + keyCode);
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mKeyCode = keyCode;
        setWillNotDraw(false);
        this.is_startAnimationTwo = context.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.is_start_animation_two);
        init(context, keyCode);
        Log.d("WakeAnimationView", "[AnimationView] end");
    }

    private void init(Context context, int keyCode) {
        Log.d("WakeAnimationView", "[init] begin");
        this.mWidthLen = context.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.bitmap_width_length);
        this.mHeightLen = context.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.bitmap_height_length);
        this.sleep_time = context.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.sleep_time);
        this.mPaint = new Paint();
        this.mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        startAnimation(keyCode);
        new Thread(this).start();
        Log.d("WakeAnimationView", "[init] end");
    }

    private void startAnimation(int keyCode) {
        Log.d("WakeAnimationView", "[startAnimation] begin");
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) this.mContext.getSystemService("window");
        int centerX = wm.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth() / 2;
        int centerY = wm.getDefaultDisplay().getHeight() / 2;
        Bitmap bitmap;
        switch (keyCode) {
            case 19:
                if (this.is_startAnimationTwo) {
                    bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gesture_wake_up2)).getBitmap();
                } else {
                    bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gesture_wake_up)).getBitmap();
                }
                initDrawable(bitmap, centerX, centerY);
                break;
            case 20:
                if (this.is_startAnimationTwo) {
                    bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gesture_wake_down2)).getBitmap();
                } else {
                    bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gesture_wake_down)).getBitmap();
                }
                initDrawable(bitmap, centerX, centerY);
                break;
            case 21:
                if (this.is_startAnimationTwo) {
                    bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gesture_wake_left2)).getBitmap();
                } else {
                    bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gesture_wake_left)).getBitmap();
                }
                initDrawable(bitmap, centerX, centerY);
                break;
            case 22:
                if (this.is_startAnimationTwo) {
                    bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gesture_wake_right2)).getBitmap();
                } else {
                    bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gesture_wake_right)).getBitmap();
                }
                initDrawable(bitmap, centerX, centerY);
                break;
            case 31:
                if (this.is_startAnimationTwo) {
                    bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gesture_wake_c2)).getBitmap();
                } else {
                    bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gesture_wake_c)).getBitmap();
                }
                initDrawable(bitmap, centerX, centerY);
                break;
            case 33:
                if (this.is_startAnimationTwo) {
                    bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gesture_wake_e2)).getBitmap();
                } else {
                    bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gesture_wake_e)).getBitmap();
                }
                initDrawable(bitmap, centerX, centerY);
                break;
            case 34:
                initDrawable(((BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gesture_wake_cusp)).getBitmap(), centerX, centerY);
                break;
            case 41:
                if (this.is_startAnimationTwo) {
                    bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gesture_wake_m2)).getBitmap();
                } else {
                    bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gesture_wake_m)).getBitmap();
                }
                initDrawable(bitmap, centerX, centerY);
                break;
            case 43:
                if (this.is_startAnimationTwo) {
                    bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gesture_wake_o2)).getBitmap();
                } else {
                    bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gesture_wake_o)).getBitmap();
                }
                initDrawable(bitmap, centerX, centerY);
                break;
            case 47:
                if (this.is_startAnimationTwo) {
                    bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gesture_wake_s2)).getBitmap();
                } else {
                    bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gesture_wake_s)).getBitmap();
                }
                initDrawable(bitmap, centerX, centerY);
                break;
            case 50:
                if (this.is_startAnimationTwo) {
                    bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gesture_wake_v2)).getBitmap();
                } else {
                    bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gesture_wake_v)).getBitmap();
                }
                initDrawable(bitmap, centerX, centerY);
                break;
            case 51:
                if (this.is_startAnimationTwo) {
                    bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gesture_wake_w2)).getBitmap();
                } else {
                    bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gesture_wake_w)).getBitmap();
                }
                initDrawable(bitmap, centerX, centerY);
                break;
            case 54:
                if (this.is_startAnimationTwo) {
                    bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gesture_wake_z2)).getBitmap();
                } else {
                    bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gesture_wake_z)).getBitmap();
                }
                initDrawable(bitmap, centerX, centerY);
                break;
        }
        Log.d("WakeAnimationView", "[startAnimation] end");
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Log.d("WakeAnimationView", "[onDraw]");
        if (!(canvas == null || this.mTempBitmap == null || this.mPaint == null)) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(this.mTempBitmap, (float) this.mLeft, (float) this.mTop, this.mPaint);
        }
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

    private void initDrawable(Bitmap bitmap, int centerX, int centerY) {
        Log.d("WakeAnimationView", "[initDrawable] begin");
        this.mBitmap = bitmap;
        this.mBitmapWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
        this.mBitmapHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
        this.mPersent = Float.parseFloat(this.mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.persent));
        this.mLeft = Math.abs(centerX - ((int) ((this.mPersent * ((float) this.mBitmapWidth)) / ((float) (this.mWidthLen * 2)))));
        this.mTop = Math.abs(centerY - ((int) ((this.mPersent * ((float) this.mBitmapHeight)) / ((float) (this.mHeightLen * 2)))));
        ScreenOn();
        Log.d("WakeAnimationView", "[initDrawable] end");
    }

    private void ScreenOn() {
        Log.d("WakeAnimationView", "[ScreenOn]");
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getContext().getSystemService("power");
        if (!pm.isScreenOn()) {
            pm.wakeUp(SystemClock.uptimeMillis());
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        if (this.mContext.getResources().getBoolean(17956895) || !(this.mKeyCode == 21 || this.mKeyCode == 22)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < this.mHeightLen; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < this.mWidthLen; j++) {
                    try {
                        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                        matrix.postScale(this.mPersent, this.mPersent);
                        this.mTempBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(this.mBitmap, (this.mBitmapWidth / this.mWidthLen) * j, (this.mBitmapHeight / this.mHeightLen) * i, this.mBitmapWidth / this.mWidthLen, this.mBitmapHeight / this.mHeightLen, matrix, true);
                        Thread.sleep((long) this.sleep_time);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    postInvalidate();
                }
            }
        }
        Log.d("WakeAnimationView", "[StartApps]:" + this.mKeyCode);
        StartApps.startFunction(this.mContext, this.mKeyCode);
    }
}
```

Comment: А вопрос какой? Вы текст ошибки перевели? 201 строку в файле AnimationView.java нашли?

Comment: @eugeneek `this.mTempBitmap` на это ссылается
видимо виноваты вот эти аргументы `this.mBitmapWidth / this.mWidthLen, this.mBitmapHeight / this.mHeightLen`

Comment: 201 строчка в AnimationView.java передаёт отрицательную или нулевую величину ширины при создании Bitmap.

Comment: @vngreez `this.mBitmapWidth / this.mWidthLen` судя из исключения не больше нуля. Не могу знать почему, код всё-таки надо долго разбирать. Возможно, вы не инициализируете `mBitmapWidth` чем-то свыше ноля

Comment: @Dmig ошибку нашел для того, чтобы вызвать эти переменные - нужно вызвать из initDrawable, а initDrawable из case. проверка в case идет по переменной keyCode, нужен keycode 0, так как вызывается 0. Видимо не должен быть ноль, и это мешает программе.
Может кто объснить что будет результатом этой команды
`this.mKeycode = Settings.Global.getInt(getContentResolver(), "key_gesture_wake_event", 0);`